# Jboss, Redeploying the application makes it running slower

Tags: java, web-applications, memory, jboss, war

I am using `jboss-5.1.0.GA` for deploying my web application.

I am copying the `App.war` into the `server/default/deploy` location.

After deploying the application first time, and when I start, it is starting smoothly.

But when I redeploy my `App.war` again using `admin console` or through backed, `Jboss` taking much time to load the `.war` file. The time for redeployment increments again for `3rd` time, for `4th` time Jboss will stuck.

Why this is happening? How can I solve this issue so that, I can avoid restarting `Jboss` each time after redeployment.

Comment: delete your `tmp` and `work` folder every time before restart.

Comment: @improver Is it necessary when I use admin console?

Comment: You probably have a memory leak in App.war so it's not getting undeployed properly and filling up JBoss's memory